# How to use Html.ListBoxFor with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to populate a ListBox. My model is just a List. I cannot find a simple explanation of parameters that I would need to use with @Html.ListBoxFor().

Here is a part of my code:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
     List<string> names = GetAllNames();

    return View(names);
}

...
```

In the view:

```
@model List<string>

...

@Html.ListBoxFor(?)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) help? And if not, what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: These are the parameters that I found in the documentation:

expression
Type: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>
An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display.
selectList
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
A collection of SelectListItem objects that are used to populate the drop-down list.


I am not sure what the first parameter means in my situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can populate you Model list in you controller action as:

```
someAction
{
    CountryModel objcountrymodel = new CountryModel();  
    objcountrymodel.CountryList = GetAllCountryList();
    return View(objcountrymodel);
}

public SelectList GetAllCountryList()
{
    List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
    objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 1, CountryName = "India" });
    objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 2, CountryName = "USA" });
    objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 3, CountryName = "Pakistan" });
    objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 4, CountryName = "Nepal" });
    SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(objcountry, "Id", "CountryName");
    return objselectlist;
}
```

and in your .cshtml, you may use it as:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryList.SelectedValue), new { @Id = "lstcountry", @style = "width:200px;height:60px;" })
```

for dealing with lists in view, you need to cast it to *SelectList* type. and in our example, *Country* is assumed to be a model for that purpose. (having key and value for selectlist)

Comment: #Zeeshan Thank you for your answer. Do I really need to create a countryModel class if I need only to display a list of names based on List<string>? I edited my question above.

Comment: @DavidShochet Not necessarily. you can also simply show countries as:

**var Countries = new [] {"Pakistan", "Nepal", "Turkey"};**

**ViewBag.CountryList= new SelectList(Countries);**


and then use it in your view. **BUT** remember! in case, you want to get selected country, you really need corresponding ID attached to it. for this purpose, Making country **Model** is efficient approach ;)

Comment: Do I need CountryModel that has a list of Countries, or it is enough to pass List<Country> to the View to be used as Model? And what is SelectedCountry in your code? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidShochet **1.** If you later have to use the value, what user has selected for country, then i'll recommend to make a model, with corresponding Ids. Otherwise, if you simply have to display the list, then list is enough (as mentioned in earlier comment)
**2.** *m.SelectedCountry* is the property of the model, for which, user can select country. (eg. SelectedCountry = Pakistan *selected from selectlist or dropdown etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a viewModel; here we suppose it's named ListBoxViewModel.

```
public class ListBoxtViewModel
{
   public string SelectedItem{get;set;}
   public List<SelectListItem> selectItemList{get;set;)
}
```

Second, add using below code to your view.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedItem, List<SelectListItem> selectItemList)
```